# MySQL IF statement with BETWEEN operator, not showing as valid

Tags: mysql, if-statement, between

Can someone tell me what is invalid about this statement? I haev tried a few different varations of this but none show as valid. I have checked SO and it says it should be valid but is not. Is it due to the BETWEEN condition?

```
UPDATE mytablename SET column_2 = IF({BETWEEN '1' AND '2'}, {new_value}, field_1) WHERE id=1

UPDATE mytablename SET column_2 = IF(column_1== 1{BETWEEN '1' AND '2'}, 1{12}, field_1) WHERE id=1
```

**UPDATE 1**
I have tried this below but same result of invalid -

```
UPDATE mytablename SET column_2 = IF(field_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 2, 12, field_1) WHERE id = 1
```

**UPDATE 2**
I also tried this but it too is invalid:

```
UPDATE mytablename SET column_2 = 12 IF(field_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 2) WHERE id = 1
```

**UPDATE 3**
Also not valid. Unexpected "{":

```
UPDATE mytablename SET column_2 = IF(field_1 BETWEEN '1' AND '2', {12}, column_2 ) WHERE id=1;
```

Comment: yes Between needs before a column like in your second update, without it is not valid

Comment: @nbk thanks. But the second is not valid. According to below nothing is valid with {}

Comment: your updat1 works just fine as ling as you have column_1 and field_1 in your database, l,lease don't mix up syntax error with other errors and check the error message

Comment: I do have a field 1 and a column 1 but it is literally telling me that the { is an unexpected character with the red X next to the whole query meaning it is not valid syntax

Comment: see my answer i added a dbfiddle to show you that it works, change the fiddle to experiment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i said in the comment you need a column

```
UPDATE mytablename SET column_2 = IF(column_1 BETWEEN '1' AND '2', {new_value}, field_1) WHERE id=1;
```

{new_vaue} is only a place holder which you must fill with a value or cloumn see below

```
UPDATE mytablename SET column_2 = IF(column_1 BETWEEN '1' AND '2', 5, field_1) WHERE id=1;

UPDATE mytablename SET column_2 = IF(column_1 BETWEEN '1' AND '2', coumn3, field_1) WHERE id=1;
```

Example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE mytablename(id int,column_2 int, field_1 int);
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO mytablename VALUES (1,0,1)
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE mytablename SET column_2 = IF(field_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 2, 12, field_1) WHERE id = 1
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM mytablename
> ```
>
> ```
> id | column_2 | field_1
> -: | -------: | ------:
>  1 |       12 |       1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2fd6808bd4134fe5be59a9bcfd741ac3)*

Comment: Thanks. This is showing as invalid according to MYPHPADMIN. I can not even run the query. Its telling me the {} are invalid

Comment: {newvalue} is of ycourse in valid, there must be a column or a value

Comment: Yes thanks. I added the values of course and it is telling me anything with  {} are invalid. I filled everything out of course

Comment: your queries arent unvalid, but your database must have a columname field_1 and a column_1

Comment: Thank you. Removing the {} was the answer. I appreciate the fiddle and the work

Answer (score 0):

(a) The curly brackets don't belong there.

(b) If the literals are meant to be integer literals, don't single quote them.

(c) In (standard) SQL the comparison operator is `=` not `==`. MySQL might accept the latter but your code gets more portable if you use `=`.

(d) You need an operand to check. So the syntax is `operand_to_check BETWEEN operand_lower_bound AND operand_upper_bound`.

Just `if(BETWEEN 1 AND 2, ...)` is therefore wrong.

`if(column_1 = 1 BETWEEN 1 AND 2, ...` is technically OK but probably doesn't do what you expect. What it does is to first compare `column_1` and `1`. If they're equal the result of that operation is `1` otherwise it's `0`. Then it checks if that `0` or `1` is between `1` and `2`.

I guess what you want is `if(column_1 BETWEEN 1 AND 2, ...)`

Comment: thanks. I am updating above since it is still showing invalid. Maybe I am misunderstanding the , ....

Comment: @Mikey; The `...` are just place holders for the rest of your code. You have to replace them with whatever 2nd and 3rd argument you have in mind for `if()`.

Comment: I updated above I ddint have any other arguments in mind there, just needing to set the result if the condition is met but youre saying that above is not valid to do so. Thus, what would the valid code be to set the condition IF x is met?

Comment: @Mikey: `if()` takes three arguments. So you need to have two more arguments...

Comment: what do I do if I dont have three arguments? I have seen a number of examples with only one argument. What am I missing? All I am trying to do is update a value if column_1 is has a value between 1 and 2

Comment: Why would you use `if()` if you haven't three arguments for it? This seems to lead to nowhere. You better delete this question and ask a new one where you elaborate on what you're trying to do. Include a [example] in the new question, i.e. the `CREATE` statement of the table and `INSERT` statements with sample data. Also include the expected result with that sample data and of course again what you have tried. Describe exactly how what you've tried failed. If there's any error messages, include them.